# R - Can I use regex to split data from one column into new multiple columns and a binary identifier?

Tags: r, regex, data-wrangling

I have a dataset about D&D Characters that looks something like this

```
Race   Class              Level   AC
Human  Fighter | Wizard    10     15
Elf    Wizard              8      10
Human  Rogue               6      12
Dwarf  Barbarian           15     18
```

I want to separate the classes that are multiclassing indicated by the "|"
Also If a character doesn't multiclass, I want to place an "NA" or "None" in that slot

```
Race   Primary_Class      Level   AC    Subclass   Multiclass
Human  Fighter             10     15    Wizard         1
Elf    Wizard              8      10    NA             0
Human  Rogue               6      12    NA             0
Dwarf  Barbarian           15     18    NA             0
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with three `ifelse`clauses, `grepl` as well as backreference with `\\1`and `\\2` respectively to match the pattern in question and `gsub` to manipulate the match:

```
df1$Primary_class <- ifelse(grepl("\\|", df1$Class), 
                            gsub("([A-z]+)\\s\\|\\s([A-z]+)", "\\1", df1$Class), df1$Class)

df1$Subclass <- ifelse(grepl("\\|", df1$Class), 
                            gsub("([A-z]+)\\s\\|\\s([A-z]+)", "\\2", df1$Class), "NA")

df1$Multiclass <- ifelse(grepl("\\|", df1$Class), 1, 0)

df1
   Race            Class Level AC Primary_class Multiclass Sub_class
1 Human Fighter | Wizard    10 15       Fighter          1    Wizard
2   Elf           Wizard     8 10        Wizard          0        NA
3 Human            Rogue     6 12         Rogue          0        NA
4 Dwarf        Barbarian    15 18     Barbarian          0        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to remove everything after `"|"`, `str_extract` to extract everything after `"|"` and use `str_detect` to detect if `"|"` is present in the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
 mutate(Primary_Class = trimws(sub('\\|.*',  '', Class)), 
        Subclass = str_extract(Class, "(?<=\\|).*"), 
        Multiclass = +(str_detect(Class, "\\|"))) %>%
 select(-Class)

#   Race Level AC Primary_Class Subclass Multiclass
#1 Human    10 15      Fighter   Wizard          1
#2   Elf     8 10       Wizard     <NA>          0
#3 Human     6 12        Rogue     <NA>          0
#4 Dwarf    15 18    Barbarian     <NA>          0
```

Comment: `Primary_class` is missing

Comment: Could also use this: `df1 %>%
  mutate(Primary_class = str_extract(Class, ".*(?=\\s\\|)"),
         Subclass = str_extract(Class, "(?<=\\|).*"), 
         Multiclass = +(str_detect(Class, "\\|")))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate` to split tthe 'Class' into two column ('Primary_Class', 'Subclass') by specifying the `sep` as zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by `|` and zero or more spaces (`\\s*`), then create the 'Multiclass' by checking whether the 'Subclass' `NA` elements

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, Class, into = c('Primary_Class', 'Subclass'),
      '\\s*\\|\\s*', extra = 'merge') %>%
     mutate(Multiclass = +(!is.na(Subclass)))
#   Race Primary_Class Subclass Level AC Multiclass
#1 Human       Fighter   Wizard    10 15          1
#2   Elf        Wizard     <NA>     8 10          0
#3 Human         Rogue     <NA>     6 12          0
#4 Dwarf     Barbarian     <NA>    15 18          0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Race = c("Human", "Elf", "Human", "Dwarf"), 
   Class = c("Fighter | Wizard", 
"Wizard", "Rogue", "Barbarian"), Level = c(10L, 8L, 6L, 15L), 
    AC = c(15L, 10L, 12L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: I think this is really interesting. I've never seen this `+` approach before. Could you please explain how does that work?

Comment: Sure! I already did it. I didn't understand why someone gave you a negative vote and I upvoted your post (just before I made this comment and question). This is probably why you're not seeing a negative number here.

Comment: @rdornas thank you.  It is a hacky way to convert TRUE/FALSE to binary.  eg. `v1 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE); +(v1)` or `as.integer(v1)` as these are stored as 1/0, and it is coerced to its integer mode with that